# Google Cloud Storage problems with HTTPS

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We’re using Google Cloud Storage service and we have some problems with SSL protocol links.
We've found out that our users now can’t access files with «https» But it worked Ok earlier.

Example:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/yareel-uploads/10000/ph/3929.jpg - LINK IS OK!

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/yareel-uploads/10000/ph/3929.jpg - LINK IS NOT OK (at least in Safari, Firefox for Mac and Chrome).

What can we do?

Comment: Both links are working for me.

Comment: Both links are OK for me. Maybe check yours files ACL ?